# In intelij How to get rid of unwanted changes to files in git

Tags: git, file, intellij-idea, git-commit

[image: Screenshot from IntelliJ]

In intelliJ When I change code 
the intelliJ stage the files for commit.
I have few files that I didn't do any change on them yet they are always stage for commit.
how can I configure the intelliJ to ignore changes in those file?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on one of the file and there should be an ignore menu item. Select this and choose to ignore all files in specified directory. Make sure the directory name refers to the .idea directory.

Click on ok and if necessary refresh the local changes view. Repeat this for other files/directories as required.

Comment: This method works for unversioned files only. If you Ignore a file that is already tracked by git in this way, it would still eventually appear in the Local changes (e.g. after Refresh).

Comment: True, getting the files out of git if they've already been committed and pulled down by other people is a bit of a pain.

Answer (score -1):

If you do not change them, why do they appear as modified? What does the diff say? Maybe it is automatic line endings conversion done by git?

Note that IDEA does not stage anything unless you explicitly call Git - Add on a file. In git status, such files will be listed as modified but not staged. So e.g. calling `git commit` manually will not commit them. In IDEA, you could just put them to a different changelist to prevent committing.

It is not possible to ignore changes to a file in IDEA, however, you could use `git update-index assume-uncahnged` or better `git update-index --skip-worktree` to tell git to ignore changes to the files.

Comment: The Admin.xml atc. are files under the .idea folder.  the user didnt changed them but the intaliJ adds to them for time to time cunfiguration changes and user usage data.

Comment: These changes could be a result of some configuration changes you do. Maybe you should commit them. Depends on what the actual difference is, of course. Sometimes configuration files get changed when it is not needed. e.g. see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-91607